# dynamically added elements won't take proper css (js only)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a `<ul>` element that gets it's `<li>`'s dynamically added, im trying to get the first `<li>` to be a bit wider then the rest with  a `width` of 63% while the others get only 60%, but for some reason the first one only gets the 60%, any idea why?

I can not use a CSS file, this has to be Javascript only.

here is my code:

```
$('.list').css({
  listStyle: 'none',
  padding: '0',
  height: '100%',
  overflowX: 'scroll',
});

$('.item-wrapper').css({
  background:'#FFFFFF',
  width: '60%',
  margin: '5px',
});

$('.item-wrapper').first().css({
  width:'63% !important',
});
```

**Edit:**
i've failed to add the resulting markup, here it is:

```
<ul class="list" style="list-style: none; padding: 0px; height: 100%; overflow-x: scroll;">
  <li class="item">
    <div class="item-wrapper" style="width: 60%; margin: 5px; background: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
        <img class="thumbnail" src="images/frame_0001.png" alt="tumbnail" style="width: 25%;">
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="item">
    <div class="item-wrapper" style="width: 60%; margin: 5px; background: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
        <img class="thumbnail" src="images/frame_0002.png" alt="tumbnail" style="width: 25%;">
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**EDIT 2:** i've rearranged ther order for the .css() functions but still no good

Comment: are these styles inline in reality of just to demo?

Comment: @atmd they are in reality, they are being added with .css() function after the ```<li>```'s are dinamically added

Comment: you might get more help here with a jsfiddle, there is not code in your question that's adding style to the ul with `.css()`, so it's hard to help without the full facts

Comment: @atmd i added the ```<ul>``` .css() code, but i was thinking... maybe the problem is how i use the .first() function?

Comment: you `ul` has no width, so when you set your `.item-wrapper` to 60%, it's 60% of what??

Comment: @atmd there's a div that wraps it that has 100% of a bigger element, they do get the 60%, for sure, its how to to make the 63% "stronger" then the 60% rule that i'm try to figure out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simply because of your use of `!important`, remove it.

It will then read:

```
$('.item-wrapper').first().css({
  width:'63%',
});
```

Other than that, your syntax is fine. Your approach is a bit questionable, but you obviously have requirements from elsewhere to avoid CSS.

More on jQuery's issue with `!important`:

http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/11173

NOTE: Since you now have no concept of precedence to play about with, ordering is significant! i.e. if you refactor your javascript in a way that sets width to 63% before it sets width to 60% elsewhere, it'll remain 60%.

Answer (score 0):

try re-ordering them

```
$('.item-wrapper').css({
  background:'#FFFFFF',
  width: '60%',
  margin: '5px'
});

$('.item-wrapper').first().css({
  width:'63% !important'
});
```

Be aware though, that you are selecting your `.item-wrapper` elements then applying the styles. this wont effect element added to the `ul` afterwards

Comment: what do you mean by "It won't do"? you need to provide more code. where is your style on the `ul`? when are you running the jquery? please add a jsfiddle

Comment: added the ```<ul>``` stlye, adding a js fiddle will take some time

Comment: Hi,

You are first setting the width of the first element to 63% and then making them all 60%. Do it the other way around and it will work.

@atmd is right!

Answer (score -1):

try it inside a function

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
$('.list').css({
  listStyle: 'none',
  padding: '0',
  height: '100%',
  overflowX: 'scroll',
});

$('.item-wrapper').first().css({
  width:'63% !important',
});

$('.item-wrapper').css({
  background:'#FFFFFF',
  width: '60%',
  margin: '5px',
});

    })
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/alaksandarjesus/2n7h51vo/)

Comment: why  is that you got inline styling too.Have anyone.